# How to create iOS universal link for ReactJS application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ios-universal-links

I am trying to create a universal link for my react application  I created an `apple-app-site-association` file inside the `react public folder`.

when I hit `{url}/apple-app-site-association` from the postman, 
getting the

> expected JSON output but the  Content-Type is null.

how to set content-type?
how to create a universal link for react-app?

Comment: do you find any solution for this.